# Overlay two audio file with audiosprite (nodejs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio, overlay

I would like to overlay two audios (like watermark). I am using  audiosprite https://github.com/tonistiigi/audiosprite but it concat two audio (first one and then second one).

I think that I need to change ffmpeg function or something like that but I don't know how I can do it.

Comment: What arguments are you passing to audiosprite ?

Comment: Two files that I would like to merge